# peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error: not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I am building an iOS application which connects to a Bluetooth device to turn some lights on and off. For these actions, I need to be paired with the device. There is also a battery service for which I do not. The situation where I connect the device for the first time (not paired before) it works like it supposed to work. I can connect when the device is in pairing mode, get a pair request and read/write the values. When I connect the device to an other device (Android in this case, but I don't think it matters much) and try to run the iOS application, it can connect to a device, discover services and the characteristics for those services, but it can't read/write those values.

The method [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic]; isn't called when I try to read all characteristics. I also tried using the setNotifyValue method with no success. When I try to read only the battery service, it works, but when the other services are enabled (which I need to be paired for) it doesn't.

When I remove the device from the Bluetooth settings and run the application again, it works like the first time and does all the things it should. Even reconnecting the devices the next day.

The question is, how can I read/write those values again without removing the device in the settings screen? Can I remove the device in the application without requiring the user to go to the Bluetooth settings? Or is it something that has to be changed on the firmware of the device?

This is (part) of my Bluetooth logic:

```
- (void)changeState:(BluetoothState)state { if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(bluetoothChangedState:)]) [[self delegate] bluetoothChangedState:state]; }

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    switch ([central state]) {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown: { NSLog(@"centralManagerDidUpdateState:CBCentralManagerStateUnknown"); break; }
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting: { NSLog(@"centralManagerDidUpdateState:CBCentralManagerStateResetting"); break; }
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized: { NSLog(@"centralManagerDidUpdateState:CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized"); break; }

        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff: { [self changeState:BluetoothStateOff]; break; }
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported: { [self changeState:BluetoothStateUnsupported]; break; }

        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn: { [self changeState:BluetoothStateOn]; [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil]; break; }
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    if ([[peripheral name] isEqualToString:@"Glasses"]) { // @TODO better check for glasses.
        [[self bluetoothManager] stopScan];

        [peripheral setDelegate:self];
        [self setPeripheral:peripheral];

        [[self bluetoothManager] connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
    return;
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    [peripheral setDelegate:self];
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];

    [self setConnected:peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected];
    if ([self isConnected]) [[self delegate] bluetoothDidConnect];
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    for (CBService *service in [peripheral services]) {
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    if ([[service UUID] isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:UID]]) {
        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in [service characteristics]) {
            if (![[characteristic UUID] isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:UID_UNKNOWN]]) {
                [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
            }
        }
    } else if ([[service UUID] isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BAS]]) {
        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in [service characteristics]) {
            [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
            //[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:%@", [characteristic UUID]);

    if ([[characteristic UUID] isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:UID_ENABLED_LEDS]]) [self getEnabledLEDs:characteristic];
    else if ([[characteristic UUID] isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BAS_BATTERY_LEVEL]]) [self getBatteryLevel:characteristic];
}
```

Comment: Since the device works fine until you pair it with another phone my suspicion is that the problem is on the device. It sounds like the keys are getting messed up

Comment: Do you know anything I can do to create a workaround? My idea was to add a description if the device was found, but could not read the values, on how to remove the device from the settings, but I prefer (for user experience) to solve this issue in the program.

Comment: Sorry, I don't.  There are no APIs available to manage pairing